# Navabhashanam in Palani Murugan Idol?

Tags: temple, idols, tamil, kartikeya

The following are my questions on this topic.

1. What are the Navabhashanas in the Palani Murugan Idol consecrated by Siddhar Bogar?
2. Where are the ingredients of Navabhashana sourced from and what is their physical and metaphysical significance?
3. What is the best available Scientific understanding of process of solidifying the Navabhashanas?
4. Also, Is there any original(or earliest) photos of the Palani Idol available before it was ravaged with scratches and etchings by devotees and alternative medicine seekers?

Comment: Its Navapaashaanam not bhashanam.   Paashan means stone, mineral.

Comment: There are four questions in a single post which is not a good thing. You will get many partial answers and incomplete answers. You should ask specifically. Also, 3rd question asks for scientific speculation which the site does not offer. That is off-topic. You can safely remove that question from the list.